# How to get “_pk_id”, “_pk_ses” in response from server when parsing

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests, session-cookies

I have been parsing one site for a long time and recently I visited this site from Google Chrome and noticed that the browser started sending something like this - _pk_id.4.825a=ce2deb8344457283.1621970312.; _pk_ses.4.825a=1 in cookies.

My question is if it possible to somehow get these cookies in the response and send them further in the next requests. I am using python requests lib and before my parser just copied cookies (ASP.NET session) from response and pasted them in further requests.

Or maybe someone can advise where I can read about this type of cookies, please? Or any ideas how to make it so that the server does not detect the parser by this cookies. I will really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: What is the site?

Comment: @QHarr https://fp.trafikverket.se/boka/#/

Comment: cross posted here: https://askpythonquestions.com/2021/05/25/how-to-get-_pk_id-_pk_ses-in-response-from-server-when-parsing/ (assuming that site isn't just pulling SO content!)

Comment: they are from matomo service (website statistics) - https://cookiedatabase.org/cookie/matomo. You shouldn't need them for later requests. The session cookie is the likely relevant one. What is it you are actually trying to do as the end objective?

Comment: @QHarr my parser collects the dates when you can pass the driver's license exam.  I am using rotating proxies and I want my parser to be as similar as possible to an ordinary user, so I copy all the headers that are the same sent by the real browser.  But I can’t get _pk_id to send it in later requests

Comment: @QHarr The parser requesting this site 1 time per 1-5 sec, so they can clearly see that they have a parser bot on their site if the parser will send requests without headers or with “strange” headers without _pk_id. So my goal is to be like a real user as much as possible

Comment: @QHarr any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

These kind of cookies are created by Matomo Analytics. You can read more about them here: https://matomo.org/faq/general/faq_146/.
And they're only active for 13 months.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30066683)